# how to save canvas image to server using c# / javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

im trying to save a image to server from canvas, when i press the upload button it just resets the canvas.im using two buttons 1 to save the canvas to a hidden field, 2 to upload the canvas.

javascipt save :

```
            saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
            alert("Please provide signature first.");
        } else {
            var signatureData = signaturePad.toDataURL();
            document.getElementById("hdnfld").value = signatureData;
            alert("signature Saved!");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Javascript upload:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
function UploadPic() {

    // generate the image data


    var Pic;
    Pic.toDataURL("image/png") = document.getElementById('hdnfld').value;
    Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

    // Sending the image data to Server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Signature.aspx/UploadPic',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + Pic + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Done, Picture Uploaded.");
        }


    });
}
</script>
```

Save Button:

```
      <a class="button save" data-action="save" href="#">Save</a>
```

upload Button:

```
      <button onclick="javascript:UploadPic();return false;">Upload Picture to Server</button>
```

c# code:

```
       public void UploadImage(string imageData)
    {
        string Pic_Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Signature.png");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Pic_Path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try updating the way you convert image

```
   var Pic =document.getElementById('hdnfld').toDataURL("image/png");
          Pic = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
```

Comment: it is still resetting the canvas and not saving image.

Comment: document.getElementById("hdnfld").value = signatureData; what is this line for ???

Comment: i was trying differnt methods, it loads the base64 string into the hidden field